# Transparent SSL/TLS proxy for non-HTTP(S) connections (tool suggestions)

Tags: security, ssl, proxy

I'm looking for a transparent SSL/TLS proxy tool to capture (and change?) generic SSL/TLS traffic (man-in-the-middle attack). Basically something that can generate certificates on the fly with its own CA. In a way, I'm looking for something like [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/), but for non-HTTP(S) traffic. Any suggestions?

Comment: How will 'something that generates certificates on the fly' be of any use? Who is going to trust it?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is to be able to read the traffic even though it's SSL/TLS encrypted. In my particular example, I'd like to listen into the XMPP/Jabber communication of WhatsApp with its servers. The HTTPS communication can be for login/registration/etc can be sniffed into with mitmproxy ([see this blog post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/05/how-to-sniff-the-whatsapp-password-from-your-android-phone-or-iphone/)) , but the actual messages are sent over a XMPP-like protocol, not HTTP(S).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a tool called [SSLsplit](http://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit) that I believe does the trick. I did not have the time to test it yet, but the man page looks like it can do plain TCP/SSL sockets.

Comment: Tutorial here: http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/08/04/use-sslsplit-to-transparently-sniff-tls-ssl-connections/

Comment: Yes, SSLsplit can do that, just use a proxy spec with `tcp` or `ssl` instead of `http` or `https`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this post in 2021 like I did. Mitmproxy now supports tcp mode so your application layer traffic need not be http.

Comment: An example would be great.